# How to prevent page from getting redirected via document.location?

Tags: javascript

I am making an auto-clicker for a website. Sometimes, when the element is clicked, it will navigate to a different page, presumably via document.location. I would like to prevent the redirect, and keep the user on the same page. The closest solution I've acheived so far is by using

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

which asks the user to confirm if they would like to remain on the page. If the user clicks cancel, then they remain on the current page, which is ideal.

The issue is that I have to manually click cancel on the prompt, which is not ideal and I don't believe I can make JavaScript auto-click cancel.

So is there a way for me to prevent the redirect, without the prompt appearing?

Comment: try with return false;

Comment: I'm not sure if a general solution is possible (because `location` is one of the few things that are, unfortunately, not monkeypatchable), but there's probably a way to prevent the redirection from happening if you can post the code around where it occurs, or the site in question. As is, without a [MCVE], I don't think any answers are possible

Comment: If this feature is for the purpose of security, a lot of web apps implement a "redirect page" which requires server-side support, but allows you to customize the message appearing to the user and warn them that they're about to leave the website. While this doesn't prevent the page navigation, I would consider this approach more user friendly as it makes the application appear less suspicious. The `onbeforeunload` popup, in my personal opinion, gives the appearance of a malicious script, even if it is attempting to protect the user.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It is possible. I just need to use:

`Object.freeze(document.location);`

Comment: Cool, I'm surprised that works! (Though, do note that it'll throw an error in strict mode, and most professional scripts run in strict mode - and a thrown error will mean that anything still on the message's current call stack will not continue to run)

Answer (score -2):

## An interesting fact

It's possible to enter in any javascript to any existing webpage.
You can do this by injecting a via third party script, or just manually enter it into the inspector like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = fuction () { return false;}
```

Websites commonly include references to third party scripts like analytics, ads, tools, libraries etc, and all of them could theoretically include a malicious script.

This is technically hijacking the existing website. It would be easy to hack peoples websites because of this, which is probably why the prompt is there as a mediating safe measure from web browsers.

Note if you close the web browser down, it won't prompt, so this method is not a fail safe anyway.

## Conclusion.

No, it's not possible.

## Alternative

Regarding the auto clicker redirect, why don't you simply put in an if condition that doesn't redirect them?